# Can't find soft deleted rows when have relations in typeorm - nestJs

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, many-to-one, soft-delete

When I try to find a row that was soft deleted , even with `{with_Deleted : true}`, returns null , but when the row was not soft-deleted it returns normal. Is there a way that it can return soft deleted rows?

conjunto-simulacoes service :

```
async getCorteById(id : number): Promise<ConjuntoSimulacoes>{
        return await this.conjuntoSimulacoesRepository.findOne({withDeleted : true,relations : ['corte'],where : {id}});
    }
```

conjunto-simulacoes Controller :

```
    @Get('/corte/:id')
    @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
    async getCorteBySimulacao(@Param('id') id : number){
        return await this.conjuntoSimulacoesService.getCorteById(id);
    }
```

conjunto-simulacoes entity :

```
@ManyToOne(() => Cortes , corte => corte.conjunto_simulacoes )
    corte : Cortes;
```

cortes entity :

```
@OneToMany(() => ConjuntoSimulacoes , conjunto_simulacoes => conjunto_simulacoes.corte )
    conjunto_simulacoes : ConjuntoSimulacoes[]
```

Comment: look at the sql query crafted by typeorm when you invoke the `getCorteById` method

Comment: @MicaelLevi how can I do that?? And if its wrong how can I adjust?

Comment: you can't adjust. It just for debug proporse. `logging: true` in your ormconfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed doing a new query , in my last query the `{with_Deleted : true}` was searching inside the table `conjunto simulacoes` and not in the table `cortes`.

New query:

```js
    async getCorteByIdWithDeleted(id : number){
        return await this.conjuntoSimulacoesRepository.query(`SELECT * FROM conjunto_simulacoes 
        as conjunto LEFT JOIN cortes as corte on corte.id = conjunto."corteId" 
        WHERE conjunto.id=${id}`);
    }
```